# Meteor error: failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: ssl, meteor, websocket, digital-ocean, meteor-up

I have been at this for days and I can't seem to find the solution for this. I have a live website, and I recently installed the ssl certificate and made the website available on https.

What's really strange is that at first the website worked well on https. For about a day or so it was live and working well. But then the next day I checked and the site is now giving me this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain.com/sockjs/421/dto72qfy/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

The navigation bar loads and the sidebar loads, but the content doesn't, it's just stuck in the 'loading' template. If I check the domain in http the website is working fine.

I am using meteor up (mup) to upload the site and digital ocean. One of the few things I have changed was the mup.json

```
...
  // Configure environment
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "https://website.com/"
    //"PORT": 80
  },
  "ssl": {
    "pem": "./ssl.pem"
    //"backendPort": 80
  },
...
```

I'm not sure how to deal with websockets and why they only have problems in https. If anyone has gotten their meteor app to work with mup and ssh I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable `websockets` by adding the following environmental variable in your mup.json

```
"DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS"=1
```

If you don't want to disable websockets, you can try option 2 from [here](https://meteorhacks.com/cloudflare-meets-meteor).

We have websockets disabled on https://saturnapi.com; you can see yourself if it is usable. [Others have also reported](https://forums.meteor.com/t/is-disabling-websockets-bad-cloudflare/3730/5) that disabling websockets still allow for a usable app, albeit a bit slower. It should depend on how your app is configured, so I recommend giving it a try and reverting to the other solutions if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Billybobbonnet It should depend on the specifics of each app. I am providing options which could be the answer the OP is looking for. The answer may not be suitable for everyone

Comment: Sure, I can add the disclaimer. Note that I also specified an alternative to disabling websockets.

Comment: Thank you.. I am looking into both alternatives now and will get back to this thread shortly

Comment: So if you disable websockets, what does it use sockjs?